# What do you want out of the Sound Design Challenge in the future?

Tags: community, skills-development, sound-design, survey

Hey folks. This is now the sixth month of the Sound Design Challenge I've been running. I've mentioned before that I'm always open to suggestions and interesting ideas. So, what are some things you'd like to see it encompass in the future?

Some examples:

- This month's addition of turning the
  entries into crowd-sourced effects
  library for all the participants.
- There's a game audio challenge in the
  works for the future that will be
  geared for newbies (like me) to
  participate as well, and I have some
  good collaborators lined up to help
  out with that one.

Let me know if there is something you're dying to try in the future, and I'll see what can be done.

*For anyone who is new and not familiar with what I'm talking about, I run a monthly sound design competition on my [website](http://www.dynamicinterference.com). This month's challenge just started too, so it's a good time to get involved. ;)*

Answer (score 2):

I think this months will give an indication into whether a collective independent libraries can be achieved. If successful maybe further collections could be incorporated into game audio (if a game programmer would get on-board to help), obviously this would take more than a month but would be very cool to be part of it.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: sorry, but i'm not quite understanding...in what way do you specifically mean getting collections incorporated into game audio. do you mean them actually being used in someone's game, or are you talking about something else?

Comment: I was thinking the community can create a collective library of sounds that could be then used for films and games. This library would be available to all users that have participated, it would act as an all round library that I think beginners like myself can turn to. Not just to use sounds and manipulate but learn how the sound was created (materials, mics, processing). I think that is the general idea I had.

Comment: Adrian, you may want to check out the sound collectors club.  http://thesoundcollectorsclub.wordpress.com/  That's pretty much already setup as you've described.  I think Shaun's sound design challenge may have different goals as a concept.

Answer (score 2):

My biggest hope is just that it keeps going, even if certain concepts end up getting revisited.  (actually, **especially** if concepts get revisited)

Comment: well, there's only one of me. lol....sooner or later, we'll end up revisiting previous concepts. i already have a few of those types of ideas in mind, i just probably shouldn't pull them out just yet. i'm glad to hear there's interest in revisiting though, thanks for the info.

Comment: I must agree. I have yet had the time available to participate (I'm hoping to hop on the Yeti challenge tomorrow!). Even if some of the same challenges came back around with different restrictions, or same restrictions place upon different challenges. Whatever, just keep going!

Answer (score 1):

I expect more specific goals, complex storytelling, far extended boundaries of sound challenge...

You already made some of unique original goals in this way like that comics swords, for what you should be really honoured. 
Im gonna participate in Yeti part. Thanks for your initiative.